# how to check if internet connection is available in MacOS Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, ping, extendscript, ecmascript-3

I used **Ping** command:

```
ping -c1 -W1 8.8.8.8
```

Works good if online, 
But in case of **internet is't available or LAN is off** the terminal **takes long time to reply** with result..

I want terminal **reply** in **maximum time 1 or 0.5 second** to use result in my

**ExtendScript** code:

```
var command = "ping -c1 -W1 8.8.8.8";

var result= system.callSystem(command);
```

I tried to set timeout using -t or -W but failed

**Edit:**

thanks to Philippe the solution is:

```
nc -z www.google.com 80 -G1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on MacOS Terminal, you can check internet connection by :

```
nc -z www.google.com 80
```

Comment: It takes some seconds too – Is it possible to set timeout?

Comment: Try -G, I think.